# security about a db connection in api routes on NextJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, next.js, trpc.io

In general, is it safe to setup a DB connection in a api route using NextJS.

- My DB credentials is going to be safe?
- The data traffic is going to be safe?

Comment: All server-side code is invisible to the user. All client-side code is visible. If you publish to https, traffic is safe.

Comment: So... every api route runs on the server-side? And if I run my app with ssr all my code is gonna be invisible to the user?

Comment: Whichever type of populating your pages with data you use, it either a) happens directly on the server or b) happens via fetch(some_api_route) which again means your backend accesses the DB then forwards the loaded data to the client-side. Visible to the user is only a) rendered HTML b) client-side JavaScript

Comment: Eventhough users wont see your API routes' codes you should still use environment variables for database credentials.

Comment: Got it @ChrisG.

Comment: Yeah, sure @Apak